# How to smoothly transition animations between divs using jquery .animate

Tags: jquery, html, css

I am building a website for a friend and am having some trouble with .animate

On .mouseenter the div gold div should get bigger by about 5% and slide to the right, same as the black div but inversely, and then return to it's original state on .mouseleave.

I've managed to get it to do that but if you hover from gold to black the animation returns itself to the original format and then starts the second animation.

Using jquery, how would I get this transition to smooth?

I currently have the animations set properly, aside from the fact that the animation is choppy between mouseEnters

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
//Gold Overlay Animation//
    $('#overlay-gold').mouseenter(function(){
        $('#overlay-gold').animate({
            width: '55%'
        })
        $('#overlay-black').animate({
            width: '45%',
            left: '55%'
        })
    })

    $('#overlay-gold').mouseleave(function(){
        $('#overlay-gold').animate({
            width: '50%'
        })
        $('#overlay-black').animate({
            width: '50%',
            left: '50%'
        })
    })
//Black Overlay Animation//
    $('#overlay-black').mouseenter(function(){
        $('#overlay-gold').animate({
            width: '45%',
            left: '0'
        })
        $('#overlay-black').animate({
            width: '55%',
            left: '45%'
        })
    })

    $('#overlay-black').mouseleave(function(){
        $('#overlay-gold').animate({
            width: '50%',
            left: '0'
        })
        $('#overlay-black').animate({
            width: '50%',
            left: '50%'
        })
    })
});
<!-- begin snippet: js hide: false console: true babel: false -->
```

```css
html, body {
    padding:0;
    margin:0;
}

#landing {
    background-image: url("images/background-mobile.jpg");
    width:100%;
    height:100vh;
    background-attachment: fixed;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-size: cover;
    background-position: center center;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    position: absolute;
}

#title {
    position: relative;
    padding:0;
    margin:0;
    color: rgb(219, 208, 208);
    z-index: 3;
    width: 100%;
    text-align: center;
    top: 45vh;
    font-size: 3em;
    text-shadow: 2px 2px 4px #000000;
}

#about {
    color: rgb(0,0,0);
    text-align: center;
    position:absolute;
    top: 50%;
    left: 50%;
    transform: translateX(-50%);
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    cursor: pointer;
}

#gallery {
    color: rgb(235,215,0);
    text-align: center;
    position:absolute;
    top: 50%;
    left: 50%;
    transform: translateX(-50%);
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    cursor: pointer;
}

#overlay-black {
    position: absolute;
    width: 100%;
    height: 50%;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0.5);
    z-index: 2; 
    cursor: pointer;
  }


  #overlay-gold {
    position: absolute;
    width: 100%;
    height: 50%;
    top: 0; 
    right: 0;
    left:0;
    background-color: rgba(235,215,0,0.5);
    z-index: 2; 
    cursor: pointer;
  }

  @media (min-width: 992px) {
    #landing {
        background-image: url("images/background.jpg");
    }

    #overlay-black {
        top:0;
        width:50%;
        height:100%;
        left: 50vw;
    }

    #overlay-gold {
        bottom:0;
        
        width: 50%;
        height:100%;
    }
    
    #title {
        position: relative;
        padding:0;
        margin:0;
        color: rgb(219, 208, 208);
        z-index: 3;
        width: 100%;
        text-align: center;
        margin-top: 1em;
        font-size: 3em;
        top: 0;
    }

    #about {
        top: 50%;
        left: 50%;
    }

    #gallery {
        top: 50%;
        left: 50%;
    }
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
    <link href="standard.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
 <script src="main.js"></script>
    <title>Bobby T Sports Art</title>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="landing">   

    <div>
        <h1 id="title">Bobby T Sports Art</h1>
    </div>
</div> 
    <div id="overlay-black"><h2 id="gallery">gallery</h2></div>
    <div id="overlay-gold"><h2 id="about">about</h2></div>

</body>
</html>
```

I expect the transition between animations to be smooth/seamless.  Currently the transition between animations takes three phases.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd like to show you an approach using CSS only I strongly recommend, so you can get rid of that jQuery.
Below an explanation step by step. In the end I will post the entire CSS code.

Before anything, replace the two background 50% opacity colors for totally opaque equivalents.

For `#overlay-black`: use `#7f7f7f` instead of `rgba(0,0,0,0.5)`.
For `#overlay-gold`: use `#f5eb7f` instead of `rgba(235,215,0,0.5)`.

It will avoid some unwanted aspects at the time of transition.

Outside the @media, remove `left: 0` for `#overlay-black`.
For it, inside @media, remove `left: 50vw`.
`width: 50%` and `right: 0` are enough.

Inside @media, add `transition: 0.36s` (it is the speed time of animation and it can be any value in seconds or miliseconds you want) for both `#overlay-black` and `#overlay-gold`.

Now, here is the trick. Inside @media, add the hover behaviour for both:

```
#overlay-black:hover, #overlay-gold:hover {
    width: 55%;
}
```

And finally, since the gold element is after the black, it is in front of the screen, so you need to add an effect for `#overlay-gold` to decrease its width when hover `#overlay-black`. It is possible using `+` selector, because they are siblings and the gold element is right after black. Add this inside @media:

```
#overlay-black:hover + #overlay-gold {
    width: 45%;
}
```

Done! Here is the complete CSS code:

```
html, body {
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
}

#landing {
    background-image: url("images/background-mobile.jpg");
    width: 100%;
    height: 100vh;
    background-attachment: fixed;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-size: cover;
    background-position: center center;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    position: absolute;
}

#title {
    position: relative;
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
    color: rgb(219, 208, 208);
    z-index: 3;
    width: 100%;
    text-align: center;
    top: 45vh;
    font-size: 3em;
    text-shadow: 2px 2px 4px #000000;
}

#about {
    color: rgb(0, 0, 0);
    text-align: center;
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    left: 50%;
    transform: translateX(-50%);
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    cursor: pointer;
}

#gallery {
    color: rgb(235, 215, 0);
    text-align: center;
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    left: 50%;
    transform: translateX(-50%);
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    cursor: pointer;
}

#overlay-black {
    position: absolute;
    width: 100%;
    height: 50%;
    right: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    background-color: #7f7f7f;
    z-index: 2;
    cursor: pointer;
}

#overlay-gold {
    position: absolute;
    width: 100%;
    height: 50%;
    top: 0;
    right: 0;
    left: 0;
    background-color: #f5eb7f;
    z-index: 2;
    cursor: pointer;
}

@media (min-width: 992px) {
    #landing {
        background-image: url("images/background.jpg");
    }
    #overlay-black {
        top: 0;
        width: 50%;
        height: 100%;
        transition: 0.36s;
    }
    #overlay-gold {
        bottom: 0;
        transition: 0.36s;
        width: 50%;
        height: 100%;
    }
    #overlay-black:hover, #overlay-gold:hover {
        width: 55%;
    }
    #overlay-black:hover + #overlay-gold {
        width: 45%;
    }
    #title {
        position: relative;
        padding: 0;
        margin: 0;
        color: rgb(219, 208, 208);
        z-index: 3;
        width: 100%;
        text-align: center;
        margin-top: 1em;
        font-size: 3em;
        top: 0;
    }
    #about {
        top: 50%;
        left: 50%;
    }
    #gallery {
        top: 50%;
        left: 50%;
    }
}
```

Comment: These answers are great!  Thanks for the help!  I'm fairly new to development and I just assumed using Jquery would be a better/ more powerful solution than CSS!  I'll try this out tomorrow!

Comment: It works as intended, now I just have to figure out how to get that background image to show.  I changed the color values back to what I had in terms of opacity, and I see what you mean with unintended consequences!

Comment: Instead of editing it, I created a JSFiddle. Maybe it can help you: https://jsfiddle.net/g1xmp93s/

Answer (score 0):

Add transitions in css to divs and change width or height:

```
div{ transition: all .5s }
```

Then change width or height with jquery or add class with different size.